# Bad geometry specifier in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to center the window of my program and I went around to search for an answer and most of them are similar, like a/2 - b/2.

I tried out the solution but got an error in return. At first, I thought it was because I was using f-string, so I switched out using the %-formatting, but it returned the same error.

For example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root.title("Testing")

window_width = 400
window_height = 200

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

x_coordinate = (screen_width/2) - (window_width/2)
y_coordinate = (screen_height/2) - (window_height/2)

root.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x_coordinate}+{y_coordinate}")

# same result
# root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (window_width, window_height, x_coordinate, y_coordinate))

root.mainloop()
```

The above returns a Bad geometry specifier error and the value "400x200+568.0+332.0". However, this was resolved when I tried using what was returned, and rerun it, but without the decimals. So it is:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Testing")
root.geometry('400x200+568+332')
root.mainloop()
```

And now the window is centered. So for that, I just used floor division and it resolved the issue. The problem is that I am not sure if that is the case because I still need to center my frame, so understanding what's happening will help prevent the same issue from occuring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `root.geometry` can't handle floats: the geometry specifier your code gives is "400x200+483.0+284.0". This should fix it:

```
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (window_width, window_height, int(x_coordinate), int(y_coordinate)))
```

Notice I call `int()`, so that the coordinates are no longer decimal numbers. This passes a geometry specifier "400x200+483+284".

It's because there is no such thing as fractions of a pixel on the computer screen.

Comment: Interestingly `tk.Canvas` doesn't mind fractions of a pixels. It might actually be rounding them internally.

Comment: @TheLizzard Maybe it's because the window manager doesn't like fractions of a pixel, and `root.geometry` is calling out to the window manager, whereas with `tk.Canvas`, all the pixel management is done inside tkinter.

Comment: @SamMatzko I haven't learned about Canvas but may I ask, are these two methods similar? If so, would it be better to just use Canvas instead because of the fraction issue?

Comment: `tk.Canvas` is not a replacement for a `tk.Tk`. While `tk.Tk` is a window, `tk.Canvas` is a widget that must be *inside* a window. So, no, the two methods are not similar.

Comment: @SamMatzko Oh, so sorry, I should've been explicit. I was talking about replacing tk.geometry with Canvas. But I guess they are still both very different from each other, right?

Comment: Yes, they are. `Canvas` is basically what it sounds like: a canvas on which you can draw lines, shapes, etc. `tk.geometry` is a way of telling a window (`tkinter.Tk`) where to be, and what size to be, on the sceen.